# Restricting access to admin module with nginx not always working

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

I need to restrict the admin module in my website. Unfortunately it's not always working. I'm migrating from apache to nginx and my nginx configuration is.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    charset utf-8;

    index index.php;

    root /websites/example/www/;

    location /admin {
            allow 192.168.3.137;
            deny all;

            try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php;
    }

location ~* \.php$ {


        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

When I try to open http://example.com/admin**/** in Firefox I am redirected to my home page. If the url is without the trailing slash http://example.com/admin, it opens the admin login which is correct. In this case access log has only record for "/" (home page). I don't have problems with Chrome and IE. I use Zend Framework for the php app.

Answer (score 0):

All files ending with `.php` are processed by the `location ~* \.php$` block, which effectively bypasses your access rules in the `location /` block.

One approach might be to use a nested location block and duplicate the PHP block. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;
}

location ^~ /admin {
    allow 192.168.3.137;
    deny all;

    try_files $uri /admin/index.php;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;
    }
}
```

The `^~` modifier ensures that the `location` block processes all URIs beginning with `/admin`. The `allow/deny` rules are inherited by the nested `location` block.

To manage the duplicated code, you may want to offload the `fastcgi` directives into a separate file and `include` them into each location.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply. 
I deleted the FF cookies and cache and the problem was solved.